# AWS IAM Policy for specific subaccount(s)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have one organization with multiple sub accounts. I would like to create IAM Policies that grant users full administrator access to  any resources in specific sub account (or sub accounts). How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

From an AWS Organization perspective, you have control over the accounts and resources via [Service Control policies (SCPs)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html).

> "However, an SCP never grants permissions. Instead, SCPs are JSON policies that specify the maximum permissions for the affected accounts."

With that in mind, you ***can't grant users*** full administrator access to any resources in a specific subaccount(s) using AWS Organization and AWS IAM Policies only.

This leads us to (roughly) 3 paths:

1. By default, if you create a member account as part of your organization, AWS automatically creates a role in the account that grants administrator permissions to IAM users in the management account who can assume the role.

The IAM Role in question is `OrganizationAccountAccessRole`. You can customize its name and use it to grant your users full administrator access across all the resources inside the AWS account.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_access.html

Observations: Since this IAM Role is created in every account. You would need to intervene and limit the IAM Cross-Account access manually in each sub-account.

2. You can use [AWS CloudFormation StackSets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/services-that-can-integrate-cloudformation.html) to deploy across multiple AWS accounts a list of IAM Roles your users could use for admin purposes (eg `RoleFullAdmin`, `RoleReadOnly`, `RoleDevOps`), and AWS Organizations enables you to create stack sets with service-managed permissions, using a service-linked role that has the relevant permission in each member account.

From your AWS Organizations management account (or [delegated administrator account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_delegate_policies.html)) you can deploy Stack Sets to current accounts and they are automatically deployed to every new account your create, keeping your resources in sync.

You can target accounts via account ID or organizational units (OUs).

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/services-that-can-integrate-cloudformation.html

Observations: Similar to 1, since you are using IAM Role Cross-Account access, you need to manually intervene in the policy trust relationship.

3. Add AWS IAM Identity Center (successor to AWS Single Sign-On) to your AWS Organizations

What you are looking for can be achieved by [Permission Sets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/permissionsetsconcept.html) in the AWS IAM Identity Center.

You can customize the access per user and have a many-to-many relationship between `User <-> Accounts <-> Roles`. You can define one or more IAM Policies in the Permission Set.

AWS provides [predefined permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/permissionsetpredefined.html) that you can use too.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/permissionsetsconcept.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/permissionsetpredefined.html

Observations: You need to add an extra resource to your AWS Organization and configure the [identity source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/get-started-choose-identity-source.html) of your users. This also requires a change in the process of "how to login to our aws account". Now you need to use the AWS SSO etc.